# Set Vimeo Embed Preferences using API

Tags: vimeo-api

Is it possible to apply the player preferences summarised on this page: `https://vimeo.com/<id>/settings/embed` using the [API PATCH method](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#identify-action)?

For example I would like to set the following flags:

- Hide Like button
- Hide Share button
- Hide Embed button

Or would it work using [getPresets](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.embed.getPresets), [setPreset](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/methods/vimeo.videos.embed.setPreset)?

Comment: These are not currently supported.

**BUT** I would love to add these. Contact vimeo at https://vimeo.com/help/contact and we can get this fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I needed the same privacy settings for all videos, I was able to does this by going to https://vimeo.com/settings/videos and selecting a default preset.